# Calculate limits of integrals

Tags: integration, limits, fourier-analysis

> Calculate the following limits: 
>   $$(a) \ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\frac{-\pi}{n}}^{\frac{\pi}{n}}\frac{n}{(nx)^2+1}e^{in^2x}dx  
> \\(b) \  \lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg(n\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_0^x\frac{se^{s^2}ds}{\sqrt{s^2+2017}}e^{inx}dx\bigg)$$

My attempt:

$(a)$ Substitute $t=nx:$
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{t^2+1}e^{int}dt \tag{1}$$

Let us define $f(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+1},$ so $(1)$ is $\hat f(-n),$ where $\hat f(n)$ is the $n-$th Fourier coefficient of $f$, and therefore by Riemann–Lebesgue lemma $(1) \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 0.$

$(b)$ I would like to use a corollary of Riemann–Lebesgue lemma: $$f \in C^k(\mathbb{T})\implies n^k\hat f(n) \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 0$$

Let us define $g(s)=\frac{se^{s^2}}{\sqrt{s^2+2017}},$ which is a continuous function, and therefore by the Fundamental theorem of calculus $G(s)=\int_0^x\frac{se^{s^2}ds}{\sqrt{s^2+2017}}$ is differentiable.

We have $\hat G(-n)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_0^x\frac{se^{s^2}ds}{\sqrt{s^2+2017}}e^{inx}dx,$ so all together $n\hat G(-n)\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 0$

Is that correct?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, your solutions to both problems work fine.

Comment: @pisco125 Thank you. One thing I noted, do I need to justify that $G(s)$ is continuously differentiable ?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary but that shouldn't be hard, since the integrand is continuous.